# Cannot execute HTTP GET call twice on nodejs/express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ftp

Using the packages `express` and ````ftp``` I try to simply get files from an ftp and return
them by HTTP GET to the client requesting.

The first request goes through fine, but when I try calling it again I run into Exception:
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

I've tried to use the solutions from [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) like having a return when sending, not setting , unfortunately none of the worked for me.

This is ALL the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const ftp = require('ftp');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const c = new ftp();

app.get('/files', (req, res) => {

    c.on('ready', () => {
        c.list((err, list) => {
            c.end();
            return res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").status(200).send({data: list});            
        });
    });

    c.connect({
        host: 'xxx',
        user: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I think it might be something with the `c.list()` callback, however I cannot for the love of god find what is wrong with it, as the `res.send()` does not get called twice anytime.

Comment: Try changing `c.on(` to `c.once(`. You likely have an issue with stale requests receiving the ready event multiple times.

Comment: `return res.setHeader` - this return is inside nested functions.  It’s not going to return from app.get, but from the innermost function.

Comment: Is there special needs that `c.end()` (ending the response process) is called before `return` statement is even reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have just one `ftp` object, and every request subscribes to (and never unsubscribes from) the `ready` event, and the `ready` event fires every time you call `connect()` , which you do for every request. So when the second request calls `connect()`, the event fires for both the first and second request. This leads to `setHeader()` being called a second time for the first request, hence the error.

Using `once()` instead of `on()` so that the event handler it only called once should resolve the issue, though there are probably better ways to write this code (use a promise API or promisify this one, only initialize a connection to the FTP server once instead of for every request).